# What does "Honeykins" mean?

Tags: suffixes, diminutive

I've heard someone, a native speaker, called his girl friend by "honeykins".

- Does it the same as "honey" or "darling"?
- Does it have special meaning other than those expressions?

Comment: It means the same thing that honey bunny sweetkins poopsy pie means ... a term of endearment.

Answer (score 32):

The word "honeykins" uses two suffixes to make it more endearing: "-kin" and "-s".

**[-kin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-kin)** is an English suffix that was used in the olden days to form diminutive forms of nouns. There are still [several dozen words in the language](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-kin) that were formed using this suffix. The more known are *pumpkin, catkin, napkin,* the less known are *ladykin, pannikin*.

It has a curious etymology, let me quote from Wiktionary:

[image]

See - it's Germanic in origin: compare with German "[Mädchen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%A4dchen)", "a girl". It is composed of the root "Magd"/"Maid", "female servant", and the diminutive suffix "-chen".

Another interesting bit, from "A History of British Surnames" by Richard McKinley, [page 100](https://books.google.ru/books?id=gcOOAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA100&ots=hA8ddm6c7S&dq=hypochoristic%20%22kin%22&hl=ru&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

It turns out Richard Daw**kin**s has this suffix too! Live and learn.

The linguistic term for a diminutive, endearing calling name is **[hypocorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocorism)** (Wikipedia):

> A hypocorism (/haɪˈpɒkərɪzəm/; from Greek ὑποκορίζεσθαι hypokorizesthai, "to use child-talk"), also known as a pet name or calling name, is a shorter or diminutive form of a word or given name, for example, when used in more intimate situations as a nickname or term of endearment. However, shortening of names is certainly not exclusive to terms of affection; indeed, in many cases, a shortened name can also be used to intimidate or humiliate. The ambiguity would need to be clarified by context.

---

According to Wiktionary, [the suffix **-s** has 5 meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-s#Etymology_5), and one of them is hypocoristic:

> Diminutive suffix:
>   *Babs; moms; [pops](http://www.nytimes.com/1990/06/17/magazine/on-language-pop-me-no-pops-pop.html); homes; Toots*

It is considered to be a shortened form of the hypocoristic diminutive suffix *-sy*.

In the "Cambridge Grammar of the English Language" by Huddleston and Pullum, both "-kin" and "-s" are mentioned briefly in Unit 5.2.1 "Evaluative morphology: Diminutives":

> The suffix **-s** also occurs after diminutive *-ie* in such playground words as *onesies, twosies, widesies*: it is doubtful whether it is here marking plural number. In addition it is found in various terms of address, such as *ducks* or *Pops*.

Comment: Excellent answer, thorough research, and +1 for pointing out that the name Dawkins is short for "little David"!

Comment: Thank-you, @CowperKettle.  As I'm only 1.67 [5 ft 6in] tall, and there's a bigger David in my extended family, I've always been Little Dave.  I'm going to insist on Dawkins in future.

Comment: i never knew Professor Dawkins was a small Digital Audio Workstation ;)

Comment: Still hear "-kins" playfully, endearingly, or mockingly appended to names today, not just in 'olden days' - but admittedly it's pretty rare.

Comment: *ducks* is a term of address?

Comment: @jDlugosz I'm no expert, but yes, I think "ducks" ("m'little ducks" etc) is still common in central England, Nottingham, Grantham sort of area.

Comment: An excellent and well-researched answer; +1

Answer (score 4):

It is an alternative way of saying honey or darling.

The addition of **kins** makes honey sound even more loving. For instance, cutie and cutie pie function the same way.

In the Urdu language, we add the suffix "jaan" to convey a more lovable tone to a precious person.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the variations used for endearment - I believe there's no significant difference. (Preferences regarding words of endearment/pet name vary from person to person/couple to couple)